# .csv is empty after reading it with pd.read_csv()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

After running

`df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')`,

my original .csv file goes blank. Is there a way to read the .csv data without emptying the original file?

Comment: what's the output of `df`?

Comment: This isn't normal behaviour, `pd.read_csv()` doesn't modify the file.

Comment: I don't think that's even possible with pd.read_csv. Have you tried several times?

Comment: It's not `pd.read_csv()`. Could you please post your full code?

Comment: Hi, is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.read_csv()` does **not** modify the file!

Here, the file before using `pd.read_csv()`:

[image]

Using it:

[image]

And now if we check it again, the file hasn't changed (as expected):

[image]

So the problem isn't with `pd.read_csv()`. I would assume that you have other code that's messing things up. Take a look and tell us, so we can help you better.